# Unable to show both mobile numbers using HintRequest

Tags: android

I am using `HintRequest` to show mobile numbers of a device in a dialog to choose one of them for SMS verification, but it shows only one mobile no always.

Below is my code:

```
// Construct a request for phone numbers and show the picker
private void requestHint() {
    HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
            .setHintPickerConfig(new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder().setShowCancelButton(true).build())
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build();

    PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
            mGoogleApiClient.build(), hintRequest);
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                RESOLVE_HINT_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**OnCreate Method**

```
mGoogleApiClient.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
    .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API);

requestHint();
```

Please suggest.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try it.

````
                .setHintPickerConfig(new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                .build())
                .setIdTokenRequested(shouldRequestIdToken())
                .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(true)
                .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
                .build();```
````

Comment: What is `shouldRequestIdToken()` and when we use `setIdTokenRequested()` method?

Comment: In Your Set Request Method